# How to post form submit to database along with ID logged in console

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to add a form submission in a bootstrap modal along with an ID of the row that was clicked to open to modal to a database. I can add the ID alone and I can add the form submission alone, but I cannot combine these two sources of information in the same database.

In the code below I get the ID (var uid), and it is logged in the console.

Is it possible to add that logged value to the ajax post? And how can I do that, so it is sent along with the form values?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){

              e.preventDefault();

              var uid = $(this).data('id'); // get id of clicked row

                 console.log(uid);

$("#bestilform").on("submit", function(e) {

    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    var antal_ordre = $("antal_ordre").val();
    var navn_ordre = $("navn_ordre").val();
    var email_ordre = $("email_ordre").val();
    var telefonnummer_ordre = $("telefonnummer_ordre").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: {'id': uid, 'antal_ordre': antal_ordre, 'navn_ordre': navn_ordre, 'email_ordre': email_ordre, 'telefonnummer_ordre': telefonnummer_ordre},
        dataType: 'json'
        })



        hide modalcontant and show order
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

             $("#seordre").show();
             $("#afgivordre").hide();
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
             console.log(status + ": " + error);
         }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

//submit form with id #submitForm
    $("#submitForm").on('click', function() {
    $("#bestilform").submit();
 });
});


 </script>
```

this  `data: 'id': uid` just gives me a 0 in the database. I am converting to integer in my php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `var uid` outside of the function which sets it and the function which needs it. Make it global for both functions. (not the best way to do). The better way to pass the parameter to the function which does submit. In this case you'll achieve consistency and your UID never will be undefined. You code may looks like ...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //define variable
 var uid;
  
  $(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // set it in one function
    uid = $(this).data('id'); // get id of clicked row
    console.log(uid);
    // and call another one
    $("#bestilform").submit();
  });

  $("#bestilform").on("submit", function(e) {
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    var antal_ordre = $("select[name$='antal_ordre']").val();
    var navn_ordre = $("input[name$='navn_ordre']").val();
    var email_ordre = $("input[name$='email_ordre']").val();
    var telefonnummer_ordre = $("input[name$='telefonnummer_ordre']").val();
  // uid will be avaiable over here
     $.ajax({
       url: formURL,
       type: "POST",
       data: {
         'id': uid,
         'antal_ordre': antal_ordre,
         'navn_ordre': navn_ordre,
         'email_ordre': email_ordre,
         'telefonnummer_ordre': telefonnummer_ordre
       },
       dataType: 'json'
     });    
     // something else???
         
     return false;
    });

  //submit form with id #submitForm
  $("#submitForm").on('click', function() {
    $("#bestilform").submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="getUser" data-id="67">click me</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>

<form method="post" action="bestil.php" data-toggle="validator" role="form" class="form-group" id="bestilform">
  <!-- antal måltider, som køber vil bestille-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Antal måltider</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="antal_ordre">
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- navn på køber-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputName1">Fulde Navn</label>
    <input name="navn_ordre" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="Indtast dit navn">
  </div>
  <!-- email på køber-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail1">Email</label>
    <input name="email_ordre" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Indtast din e-mail" data-error="Hov! Det er vist ikke en email...">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- telefonnummer på køber-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputPhonenumber1">Telefonnummer</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">+45 </span>
      <input name="telefonnummer_ordre" data-minlength="8" type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPhone1" placeholder="Indtast dit telefonnummer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--modal footer-->
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lavbestillingaccepter">Tilbage
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitForm" form="bestilform">Køb Måltid!
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ahh perfect! That did it! Thanks so much for your help! I was getting an empty entry along with the form entry in my database, but I just deleted this part, and then it worked perfectly.

        // and call another one
       $("#bestilform").submit();

Comment: Glad it helped. Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)